# Can we do video data augmentation with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is it possible to apply video data augmentation on a dataset using Keras ? I know that this is a possibility for images, like it is explained [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), but I didn't find the equivalent for video clips.

My dataset contains video clips of 500 frames. When I apply a transformation on one frame, I need it to be the same for the 499 following frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use ImageDataGenerator class in keras, I think you need to use [apply_transform](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#apply_transform) functions  in every frame manually. For example

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator()
for i in range(length_video):
     new_frames[i] = gen.apply_transform(frames[i], {'ty':100, 'theta':10})
```

Anotherway, you can try this https://github.com/okankop/vidaug  it's make for video augmentation

Comment: If you apply rotation as an augmentation method, you should specify a rotation angle range [0, theta]. Does it mean, that it applies the rotation randomly for each frame with an angle comprised within the interval [0, theta] ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vidaug` library from [here](https://github.com/okankop/vidaug).

You can also use `scipy.ndimage` for applying some simple multidimensional operations. Here is the link to [Multidimensional image processing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) package.